# xpath in selenium for clicking the element

Tags: selenium, xpath

This is the HTML code, for the box, please advice me on how to find the  correct xpath for any element in this box.
The box contains list of  elements and the element is transferred from left to right box or vice versa when clicked.

---

```
<div id="companyIndustry" class="form-group" style="margin:0">
    <select id="my-select-industry" name="segmentdiv:companyIndustries" multiple="multiple" size="8">
        <option value="1">Agriculture and Mining - Farming and Ranching</option>
        <option value="2">Agriculture and Mining - Fishing, Hunting and Trapping</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Please, show what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Xpath can be:-

```
//select[@id='my-select-industry']/option[@value='2']
```

In this case you can use

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("my-select-industry")));
```

To select its option say 'Agriculture and Mining - Fishing, Hunting and Trapping' you can do

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Agriculture and Mining - Fishing, Hunting and Trapping ");
```

or

```
dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
```

or

```
 dropdown.selectByValue("2");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//option"));
```

You could also search for 'option' tags with relative xpath (searching downward from a 'known' [previously found] element), but that would require you to add a '.' dot instead of double slash before 'option'.

e.g.

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("my-select-industry"));     
List<WebElement> options = selectElement.findElements(By.xpath("./option"));
```

There's a similar example of what you're trying to do here: http://forum.testproject.io/index.php?topic=19.0